# Adding to url using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a url like `http://res.cloudinary.com/damzjhbip/image/upload/c_fit,h_600,w_600/v1460061761/p9opxivnzwbxzmrwhagk.jpg`

I want to break the url into the below and add a value to the centre of the url like this

```
"http://res.cloudinary.com/damzjhbip/image/upload/c_fit,h_600,w_600/" + "c_fill,e_vibrance,h_600,w_600/" + "v1460061761/p9opxivnzwbxzmrwhagk.jpg"
```

Comment: starting of url :`http://res.cloudinary.com/damzjhbip/image/upload/`  and endting of url  : `v1460061761/p9opxivnzwbxzmrwhagk.jpg` remains fixed ?

Comment: well it s a pattern for the urls but i just need to input my values into that point in all the urls

Comment: @Didi This "pattern" is the second to the last directory? Or is it the directory located 3 levels down?

Comment: @zer00ne this is the pattern http://res.cloudinary.com/damzjhbip/image/upload/c_fit,h_600,w_600/v1460061761/p9opxivnzwbxzmrwhagk.jpg   BUT i want to put some numbers after the c_fit,h_600,w_600 like ...c_fit,h_600,w_600/c_fill,e_vil.../

Answer (score 0):

Make function like this :

```
<script>
 function updateURL(input) {
    var  startingURL = "http://res.cloudinary.com/damzjhbip/image/upload/ ";
    var endingURL = "/v1460061761/p9opxivnzwbxzmrwhagk.jpg";

    return startingURL + input + endingURL ;


 }
</script>
```

Comment: ok this wont work because the url i put at first is the pattern in which all the urls will come so i am trying to split the url at that point and insert my numbers n join again

Comment: Please explain in details so, i can help you further